# How to remove all live link except "dummy" anchor text with regex

Tags: regex

input:

```
Lorem <a href="random1.com">Ipsum</a> is simply <a href="random2.com">dummy</a> text of the <a href="random3.com">printing</a> and typesetting industry.
```

Desired output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="random2.com">dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

How to remove all live link except "dummy" anchor text with regex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `python`:

```
import re
str = 'Lorem <a href="random1.com">Ipsum</a> is simply <a href="random2.com">dummy</a> text of the <a href="random3.com">printing</a> and typesetting industry.'
print(re.sub(r'<a href=[^>]+>(?!dummy)(.*?)</a>', r'\1', str))
```

With `perl`:

```
$_ = 'Lorem <a href="random1.com">Ipsum</a> is simply <a href="random2.com">dummy</a> text of the <a href="random3.com">printing</a> and typesetting industry.';
s#<a href=[^>]+>(?!dummy)(.*?)</a>#$1#g;
print "$_\n";
```

The result:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="random2.com">dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```